# Create two or more GUI working in different context

Tags: java

I want to create two or more instances of the same GUI class that working each on its context.
Each GUI shows a different graph and there are many sliders in a single GUI that working on its own graph.

I already created and displayed these GUI and they show their own graph and sliders.
When I change the parameter from the slider, for example in the first GUI, this GUI takes the graph of the last GUI created and show it on its panel and working with it.

I have difficulty to show some code, as it is too long and separated into many packages.
I hope that the problem is clear.

I created these GUIs inside a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
   new graphGUI();
}
```

In `public class graphGUI`, there is a constructor that calls a `initialize()` method that initializes GUI in which there is a call to method to create a graph and then to a method to visualize it.

If it is unclear I try to add some more detail about code.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Please post the error you are getting.

Comment: I haven't no error, simply gui1 and gui2 are created with graph1 and graph2, respectively. When I modify (with a slider) some parameters of graph1 in gui1, it works on graph2 always on gui1 as if graph1 is overwrite.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand the comment you added.